# Qt / QML - Grouping and Reusing Elements

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to best organise my QML?

Currently for common single components I make a new QML file and add it to a `Common` directory under my resources.

E.g. My `Label.qml`

```
Text{
    width: parent.width * 0.5
    height: parent.height * 0.1
    color: "#ffffff"
    font.underline: true
    font.pointSize: 16
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
}
```

And then in my `Form.qml` I can import and use it like this:

```
   import "Common"

    Page {

        Label{
            id: username_lbl
            text: "Username"
            anchors.topMargin: parent.height * 0.1
        }

    ...
    }
```

But how would I do the above if I want to group together multiple components and reference them for use with connections?

For example I'd like a pair of buttons that sit at the bottom of a page (**below is just an example and doesn't work**):

So I'd like to have a `ButtonPair.qml` which would like a bit like this:

```
    Button {
        id: left_btn
        width: parent.width * 0.5
        height: parent.height * 0.1

        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right

    }

    Button {
        id: right_btn
        width: parent.width * 0.5
        height: parent.height * 0.1

        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
    }
```

And then in my `Form.qml` I'd like to use these buttons and add an event handler to each:

```
import "Common"

Page {

    ButtonPair{id: back_forward_buttons}

    Connections {
        target: back_forward_buttons.left_btn
        onClicked: {
            stackView.pop();
    }

    Connections {
        target: back_forward_buttons.right_btn
        onClicked: {
            stackView.push("AnotherPage.qml");
    }

}
```

Do I need to wrap my `ButtonPair` in a `Component` and use a `Loader` on my page and if so how do I then get to the individual left/right buttons in order to bind to `onClicked`?

Comment: You should wrap the two buttons in a `Item` (or *Layout) element and expose the two children via alias properties in that element. You can then reference the wohle element in your code as usual. The only downside is that you have to take extra care regarding the organization of the buttons. I would recommend going with a `GridLayout` and simply expose everything as property that you need to be configurable (and maybe even use JS for dynamic item organization). It really depends on how exactly you expect the pair to behave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a component is designed, it is considered a black box that has properties and signals that must be viewed from the outside.

For example in your case ButtonPair must expose 2 signals: one when the left button is pressed and another when the right button is pressed, another thing that I have added are 2 properties to be able to establish the name of the buttons.

I see that you have set the height of the buttons as 10% of the height of the father and should be in the lower part and if you want to use that same component on the top? I would have to create another topButtonPair component, and if I want them to be on the right, etc. For the size should be established when the component is created not in the implementation. In this case each button must occupy half of the parent item.

Using the above we obtain the following:

**ButtonPair.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Item{
    // expose properties and signals
    property string leftname: ""
    property string rightname: ""
    signal leftClicked()
    signal rightClicked()

    // internals
    RowLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0
        Button {
            text: leftname
            onClicked: leftClicked()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
        Button {
            text: rightname
            onClicked: rightClicked()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** *The use of the layout is optional, you could use the anchors.*

Now used on the page:

```
Page {

    // other components

    ButtonPair{
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 0.1*parent.height // <--- Here the height is established
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        leftname: "left text"
        rightname: "right text"
        onLeftClicked: console.log("left clicked")
        onRightClicked: console.log("right clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exposing the signals is what I was missing. I agree with not fixing dimensions and anchors inside the re-usable component, but is there a way to store a common set of anchors for re-use? E.g. if I have a `TitleLabel` that  always has the same anchors / dimensions no matter the page (fixed at the top) is there a way to store and re-use these values? In QML it'd be something like `TitleLabel { MySavedAnchors }`

Comment: @user6635665 The anchors is not a property, it is the connection between 2 properties, that is, the geometry of one element with respect to another. It can not.If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Will do and thanks again - as a final question around this: what would be the best way to store commonly used strings? Wrap them as properties inside an item similar to above?

Comment: Store strings? If you are going to store string use a singleton and save the most common phrases in it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the black-box appraoch taken by @eyllanesc is the better one and should be preferred whenever possible. However, if you really need to access child items from the outside, you can:

ButtonPair.qml:

```
Item {
    property alias leftButton: left_btn
    property alias rightButton: right_btn

    // … declarations of left_btn and right_btn as in your question
}
```

Usage:

```
ButtonPair {
    leftButton {
        onClicked: {
            stackView.pop();
        }
    }
    rightButton {
        onClicked: {
            stackView.push("AnotherPage.qml");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use it in `Connections`. However, in 95% of cases you should forward properties and signals as in @eyllanesc’s approach, which leads to a much cleaner and readable interface.

Comment: It would also be advisable to point out that the alias only supports a single level of hierarchy (I think maximum 2), that is, for example: `property alias foo_property: left_btn.some_property1.some_property2` generate errors.